# How do I fix my Visual Studio forms not focusing?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a button which opens a new form, but every time I press it I have to click my app from the taskbar to open it because it doesn't focus, my form border style is set to none.

This is the code I am using for the button:

```
    private void Button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        Visible = false;
    }
```

I have tried changing the form border style, writing `f2.Activate`, `Form2.Focus` and other things but nothing works (also I am brand new to programming so sorry if this is a dumb post).

EDIT: I set the WindowState to minimized and it fixed my problem, thanks Jimi!

Comment: Why are you showing the new form and hiding the current form? What is the actual relationship between the two forms?

Comment: Maybe you have set the Form's `WindowState = Minimized`. If that's the case, set it back to `Normal`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oke so I Dont exacly know what your intent, but you can try ShowDialog(). That force the main form to wait until the f2 is closed(). And the f2 is always on top of the main if it is alive.

Comment: Or you can use f2.TopMost = true; this will get the f2 always top of all window of your computer. Itt will how ever not focus it if you click out of the f2 window but stay in front

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can use the Activate() method to set the focus to the new form after showing it.

```
private void Button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    f2.Activate(); // Set focus to the new form
    //f2.Visible = false;
}
```

Also i would remove the Visible = false, because that would only hide the Form. In your question it seems like this is not what you want to do.

Comment: Visible = false Hide the main form not the f2 like in your case.